# Comparar Background com Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Estou com um problema em comparar o `Background` de um `ImageButton` com um `drawable`

`IB6` é o meu `ImageButton` e queria ver se tem o `drawable def`, quando chega a este `if` a aplicaçao para e dá erro no `equals`

```
if (IB6.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.def).getConstantState()))
```

O programa vai abaixo porque estou a comparar mal o `Background` do `ImageButton` com o `drawable`.

Como faço um `if` a verificar se o `Background` de `IB6` é igual ao `drawable def`??

Comment: Olá Leandro, poderia adicionar o erro que ocorre? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: editei a pergunta, basicamente queria saber como posso comparar O `Background`de um `ImageButton` com um dado `drawable`?

Comment: Podes tentar de uma maneira mais "rasa", sem a necessidade de fazer conversões de imagens e ter o risco de gerar falso-verdadeiro.
Utilizei em projetos passados, a propriedade "getTag()" e "setTag()", que me auxiliaram de forma rápida e simples.

Comment: como faço isso? `getTag()` e `setTag()`

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageInteresse);

imageView.setTag("1");

iamgeView.getTag();

Answer (score 4):

`getDrawable()` não retorna o background mas sim a imagem atribuída por `android:src`.

Em vez de `getDrawable()` use `getBackground()`

```
if (IB6.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.def).getConstantState()))
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente Transformar os `drawable` em `Bitmap` e compare através do método [sameAs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)).

Segue um exemplo:

```
       final ImageButton buttonImage = ImageButton.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin));

        if(null != buttonImage.getDrawable()){
            final Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_facebook, null);



            if(  getBitmap(buttonImage.getDrawable()).sameAs(getBitmap(drawable)) ){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "São iguais", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não são iguais", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

}
```

método para transformar em Bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap result;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        result = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else {
        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        // Some drawables have no intrinsic width - e.g. solid colours.
        if (width <= 0) {
            width = 1;
        }
        if (height <= 0) {
            height = 1;
        }

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Eu estive perto de resolver mas á um erro é que o meu `IB6.getDrawable()` é sempre `null` e ele começa com uma imagem no `Background`, porque está sempre a `null`? Ate trocando de imagem dá `null`

Comment: A resposta do @ramaral deve lhe servir!